# Optimized Retrieve datas grouped by another Collection in Firebase's Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, promise, google-cloud-firestore

I have two collections in my Firestore databse, equivalent to:

```
// ItemCategories collection
{
    id_category_1: {
        name: 'Category 1',
    },
    id_category_2: {
        name: 'Category 2',
    },
    id_category_3: {
        name: 'Category 3',
    },
    // ...
}

// Items collection
{
    id_item_1: {
        CategoryId: 'id_category_1',
        name: 'Item 1',
    },
    id_item_2: {
        CategoryId: 'id_category_1',
        name: 'Item 2',
    },
    id_item_3: {
        CategoryId: 'id_category_3',
        name: 'Item 3',
    },
    id_item_4: {
        CategoryId: 'id_category_2',
        name: 'Item 4',
    },
    // ...
}
```

I'd like to retrieve and format my Items to be separated by categories, as such:

```
const ItemList = {
    'Category 1': [
        {
            id: 'id_item_1',
            CategoryId: 'id_category_1',
            name: 'Item 1',
        },
        {
            id: 'id_item_2',
            CategoryId: 'id_category_1',
            name: 'Item 2',
        },
    ],
    'Category 2': [
        {
            id: 'id_item_4',
            CategoryId: 'id_category_2',
            name: 'Item 4',
        },
    ],
    'Category 3': [
        {
            id: 'id_item_3',
            CategoryId: 'id_category_3',
            name: 'Item 3',
        },
    ],
};
```

I'm currently working with a mess of Promises:

```
// Function to retrieve Items for a given CategoryId
const getItemsByCategory = async CategoryId => {
    const Items = await new Promise(resolve => {
        firebase
            .firestore()
            .collection('items')
            .where('CategoryId', '==', CategoryId)
            .orderBy('name', 'ASC')
            .onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
                const values = [];
                querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
                    values.push({
                        ...doc.data(),
                        key: doc.id,
                    });
                });
                resolve(values);
            });
    });
    return Items;
};

// Function to actually get all the items, formatted as wanted
export const getItemList = () => {
    return dispatch => { // I'm in a Redux Action
        const Items = {};

        firebase
            .firestore()
            .collection('itemCategories')
            .orderBy('name', 'ASC')
            .get() // Categories can't be changed
            .then(querySnapshot => {
                const Promises = [];
                querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
                    const category = doc.data().name;

                    const P = new Promise(resolve => {
                        getItemsByCategory(doc.id).then(values => {
                            const result = {
                                category,
                                values,
                            };
                            resolve(result);
                        });
                    });

                    Promises.push(P);
                });

                Promise.all(Promises).then(values => {
                    values.forEach(v => {
                        Items[v.category] = v.values;
                    });

                    // Here I have the formatted items
                    console.log(Items); 
                    //dispatch(setItemList(Items)); // Redux stuff
                });
            });
    }
};
```

This code is working, but I feel like there should be ways to optimize it. I can see at least two issues with this:

- this code makes **(N+1) Firestore calls** *(where N is the number of Categories)*. As Firebase charges every call, I can't see this scaling.
- We have to **wait for N promises** to actually display datas ; execution time might be a problem if the count of categories grows too much.

Is there any better solution than what I got to?

Answer (score 1):

> As Firebase charges every call, I can't see this scaling.

Firestore doesn't charge based on "calls".  It charges for number of documents read and amount of data transferred.  If you need to read all the categories, then you will just pay for a number of documents read about of that collection.  It doesn't matter how many calls it took you to read those documents (the exception being that a query that returns 0 results still incurs one read).

There is not a whole lot of difference, in practice, between waiting for 1 query that returns N documents, or N queries that each return 1 document.  You are still just waiting for N documents either way.  With Firestore, there are no queries that don't scale well.  The limiting factor is **always** going to be based on the number of documents received, not the number of queries.  Your code is going to mostly spend time just waiting for the results to transfer.  Of course, there is a practical upper bound to the number of things you can hold in memory, but the number of promises is not going to be a big deal.

Aside from that, I don't understand why you are using `onSnapshot` in `getItemsByCategory`.  Seems like you just want to use get() instead of receiving just one result in a listener.  Your code will be much simpler that way.

Comment: I confused "calls" and "reads", it's much clearer now. As I understand it, in the end it doesn't matter how you get the datas since it is the amount of documents that defines the "price".
In theory, I could have only one collection of Categories with nested collection of Item in each document. Would this be better? I feel like nested collection is not so good.
Finally, why `ref.get().then(querySnapshot => {...})` is simplier than `ref.onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {...})`? Can you explain this part? Users can add/edit/remove Items, so I'd like to retrieve them "live".

Comment: You should organize your data in the way that suits your queries.  There is not "one correct way" to use a NoSQL database.  It always depends on how you intend to query it.

Comment: It sounds like you have additional questions.  Please post those separately, as it's not a good idea to drag them out into a long series of comments.